# Corda: Alternative to Spring application for performing the RPC connection to the Corda node

Tags: spring, corda

We are working on a POC that uses Corda 4.0, Spring 4.3.11 and Springboot 2.0.2.
AngularJs is used for Front-end and PostgreSQL for database.

Is there an alternative to Spring application that would facilitate the RPC connection to the Corda node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Braid Server with Open API generator to generate client API's in more than 40 languages; read about it [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/cordacon-2019-highlights-braid-server-and-openapi-generator-for-corda-flows-api-s-d24179ccb27c).

There's a Braid server example (with a React font-end) [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/iou-reactfrontend-Braid).